# FPS drop in games after installing and uninstalling a GPU

Tags: nvidia, games, gpu, framerate

I have recently purchased an NVidia GTX 1050 Ti OC WF3 but I did not realise that my PSU would be underpowered for it.

I've uninstalled the GPU and now my FPS in games has halved.

In games such as CSGO, which I had 60FPS on, are now running only at 30FPS.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Get a better PSU?

Comment: I won't bother with changing PSU, i'll get a GT 730 soon but I still want to find out how to fix the problem of my FPS halving.

Comment: @Fext922 You understand the 1050 uses only around ~40 W more than the 730? I don't think the PSU's the problem. And BTW, the 1050 is **much, much** more worth it than a 730. You could always underclock the 1050 and still get really good performance vs the 730.

Comment: I would suggest you to use windows for CSGO. I had the same issue on ubuntu. I think the game is not optimised properly for ubuntu/linux and with you 1050 card you can get 120+ fps.